# error installing data.table v1.10.5 (dev)

Tags: r, data.table, failed-installation

I am trying to install the dev version data table (v1.10.5) on a Windows computer. I followed the [instructions on the official data.table website](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation#windows), but got the following errors:

```
install.packages("data.table_1.10.5.zip", repos=NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/.../R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : zip file ‘data.table_1.10.5.zip’ not found

install.packages("data.table_v1.10.5.zip", repos=NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/.../R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : zip file ‘data.table_v1.10.5.zip’ not found
```

How can I install `data.table v1.10.5`?

Comment: Have you downloaded this version onto your hard drive? are you in the directory to which you downloaded the file? Maybe try `file.exists` to check if a file with such a name is in your current directory or `dir` to get the name of all files, etc.

Comment: No, I had not downloaded. My bad. The explanations on the data.table 
 installation page are a bit hard to understand though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install using `install_github` from `devtools`

```
remove.packages("data.table")
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes=FALSE)
library(data.table)
test.data.table()
```

Use test.data.table() to test the functions :)